# find all users who has over N process and echo them in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I'm writing script is ksh. Need to find all users who has over N process and echo them in shell.
N reads from ksh.

I know what I should use `ps -elf` but how parse it, find users with >N process and create array with them. Little troubles with array in ksh. Please help. Maybe simple solutions can help me instead of array creating.

```
s162103@helios:/home/s162103$ ps -elf 
     0 S  s153308  4804     1   0  40 20        ?  17666        ? 11:03:08 ?           0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon --oa
     0 S     root  6546  1327   0  40 20        ?   3584        ? 11:14:06 ?           0:00 /usr/dt/bin/dtlogin -daemon -udpPor
     0 S webservd 15646   485   0  40 20        ?   2823        ?     п╪п╟я─я ?           0:23 /opt/csw/sbin/nginx
     0 S  s153246  6746  6741   0  40 20        ?  18103        ? 11:14:21 ?           0:00 iiim-panel --disable-crash-dialog
     0 S  s153246 23512     1   0  40 20        ?  17903        ? 09:34:08 ?           0:00 /usr/bin/metacity --sm-client-id=de
     0 S     root   933   861   0  40 20        ?   5234        ? 10:26:59 ?           0:00 dtgreet -display :14
     ...
```

when i type

```
ps -elf | awk '{a[$3]++;}END{for(i in a)if (a[i]>N)print i, a[i];}' N=1

s162103@helios:/home/s162103$ ps -elf | awk '{a[$3]++;}END{for(i in a)if (a[i]>N)print i, a[i];}' N=1
root 118
/usr/sadm/lib/smc/bin/smcboot 3
/usr/lib/autofs/automountd 2
/opt/SUNWut/lib/utsessiond 2
nasty 31
dima 22
/opt/oracle/product/Oracle_WT1/ohs/ 7
/usr/lib/ssh/sshd 5
/usr/bin/bash 11
```

that is not user /usr/sadm/lib/smc/bin/smcboot 
there is last field in ps -elf ,not user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal `ps` command you want to use here is `ps -eo user=`.  This will just print the username for each process and nothing more.  The rest can be done with awk:

```
ps -eo user= |
  awk  -v max=3 '{ n[$1]++ }
    END {
      for (user in n)
        if (n[user]>max)
          print n[user], user
  }'
```

I recommend to put the count in the first column for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this(assuming 3rd field of your ps command gives the user id):

```
 ps -elf | 
   awk '{a[$3]++;}
   END {
     for(i in a)
       if (a[i]>N)
         print i, a[i];
   }' N=3
```

Comment: yes 3rd field,but it outputs wrong information. It output random information(UID and CMD and other from ps -elf),not only names I need only names.(UIDs)

Comment: `F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
5 S cl32387  18246 18241  0  80   0 -  5895 ?      Mar16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vs5 S cl32387  18469 18436  0  80   0 - 13200 ?      09:51 ?        00:00:00 sshd: cl32387@pts/2
0 S cl32387  18481 18469  0  80   0 -  4470 -      09:51 pts/2    00:00:00 -bash
0 R cl32387  18842 18481  0  80   0 -  3431 -      09:51 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -elf`

Comment: I am getting proper output for the same..keep in mind, the solution provided will list all the users and their no. of processes if it is more than 3(N=3).

Comment: There's my edited post on the top. Guru, please,check it. There is information about output ps -elf ant your command in formatted

Comment: with nawk it works fine but number of count is wrong.
For example:
`root 136`. `ps -elf` show less than 136

Comment: Use -v N=3 before the awk program text.  It's the preferred way these days.

Comment: @AlexZern You also added the `ps` output to your question to reduce clutter you can remove the comments with the sample and the apology. (As the author of a comment you'll see a little cross at the end. Click that to delete.)

Answer (score 0):

```
read number    
ps -elfo user= | sort | uniq -c | while read count user
do 
    if (( $count > $number )) 
    then 
      echo $user  
    fi  
done
```

That is best solution and it works!